# use ngModel inside <p> tag in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular

Html code:

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let card of allCards">
<p class="card-text">Card Color: {{card.color}}</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary product-btn" (click)="addCard()">Add Card</button>"
```

Here I also want to bind the value "card.color" into another variable (maybe using ngModel) so that I can use it inside my typescript file in angular 8.

I tried the below but not working:

```
<p class="card-text" [(ngModel)]="cardColor">Card Color: {{card.color}}</p>
```

Comment: Would you show ts file as well where card is initialized?

Comment: export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  public allCards:any;

Comment: Edit your original question, please.

Comment: Basically when I click the button "Add Card", I want to use the value card.color

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could send the contents to the button `click` event's handler.

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let card of allCards">
<p class="card-text">Card Color: {{card.color}}</p>
<button 
  type="button" 
  class="btn btn-sm btn-primary product-btn" 
  (click)="addCard(card.color)"
>
  Add Card
</button>
```

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
addCard(color: any) {
  // use `color` here
}
```

Comment: I am using angular 8 and typescript. Inside type script file how we can use the color without binding it ?

Comment: The `addColor()` fuction would be defined in the typescript file. Use it there. Now the value is sent as an argument to it. If you're new to Angular, please take your time to go through their official tutorial. It's relatively quick and introduces the basics.

Comment: I want to use the value that is printed in the below statement :<p class="card-text">Card Color: {{card.color}}</p> inside my ts file.

Comment: `(click)="addCard(card.color)"` - what do you think is happening here?